# Python Pandas - Replace NaN values of a column with respect to another column using interpolate()

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, nan

I am facing problem while dealing with NaN values in `Temperature` column with respect to column `City` by using `interpolate()`.

The df is:

```
data ={
    'City':['Greenville','Charlotte', 'Los Gatos','Greenville','Carson City','Greenville','Greenville' ,'Charlotte','Carson City',
                'Greenville','Charlotte','Fort Lauderdale', 'Rifle', 'Los Gatos','Fort Lauderdale'],
    'Rec_times':['2019-05-21 08:29:55','2019-01-27 17:43:09','2020-12-13 21:53:00','2019-07-17 11:43:09','2018-04-17 16:51:23',
             '2019-10-07 13:28:09','2020-01-07 11:38:10','2019-11-03 07:13:09','2020-11-19 10:45:23','2020-10-07 15:48:19','2020-10-07 10:53:09',
            '2017-08-31 17:40:49','2016-08-31 17:40:49','2021-11-13 20:13:10','2016-08-31 19:43:29'],
    'Temperature':[30,45,26,33,50,None,29,None,48,32,47,33,None,None,28],
    'Pressure':[30,None,26,43,50,36,29,None,48,32,None,35,23,49,None]
}
df =pd.DataFrame(data)
df
```

*Output:*

```
    City              Rec_times            Temperature   Pressure
0   Greenville      2019-05-21 08:29:55        30.0        30.0
1   Charlotte       2019-01-27 17:43:09        45.0         NaN
2   Los Gatos       2020-12-13 21:53:00        26.0        26.0
3   Greenville      2019-07-17 11:43:09        33.0        43.0
4   Carson City     2018-04-17 16:51:23        50.0        50.0
5   Greenville      2019-10-07 13:28:09        NaN         36.0
6   Greenville      2020-01-07 11:38:10        29.0        29.0
7   Charlotte       2019-11-03 07:13:09        NaN         NaN
8   Carson City     2020-11-19 10:45:23        48.0        48.0
9   Greenville      2020-10-07 15:48:19        32.0        32.0
10  Charlotte       2020-10-07 10:53:09        47.0        NaN
11  Fort Lauderdale 2017-08-31 17:40:49        33.0        35.0
12  Rifle           2016-08-31 17:40:49        NaN         23.0
13  Los Gatos       2021-11-13 20:13:10        NaN         49.0
14  Fort Lauderdale 2016-08-31 19:43:29        28.0        NaN
```

I want you to deal the `NaN` values in the column `Temperature` by grouping them based on `City` using interpolate(method='time').

*Ex:*

Consider `City` as 'Greenville' it has 5 temperatures (`30,33,NaN,29` and `32`) recorded at different times. The `NaN` value in `Temperature` is replaced by a value by grouping the records by the `City` and using `interpolate(method='time')`.

*Note: If you know any other optimal method to replace `NaN` in `Temperature` you can use as 'Other solution'.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lambda function with `DatetimeIndex` created by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df["Rec_times"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Rec_times"])

df['Temperature'] = (df.set_index('Rec_times')
                       .groupby("City")['Temperature']
                       .transform(lambda x: x.interpolate(method='time')).to_numpy())
```

One possible idea for replacing missing values after `interpolate` is to replace them by the `mean` of all values like:

```
df1.Temperature = df1.Temperature.fillna(df1.Temperature.mean())
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than mine. I like the method chaining!

Comment: @FredMaster - ya, also not removed datetimes column

Comment: @jezrael Do you have any optimal solution to deal the remaining NaN (like for 'Rifle' city)?

Comment: @jezrael I said you can use any optimal method it's not mandatory to use interpolation only (to deal remaining NaN). And also have a look at 'Note', if you have any other solution (other than interpolation) which you think can be well suited (for whole df) you can use.

Comment: @Abhi - Added possible solution to answer.

Comment: @jezrael If you have any other solution (other than interpolation) which you think can be well suited (for whole df) you can use as 'Other solution'.

Comment: @Abhi - Hmm, problem is if use `mean`, `median`, interpolate and all values in groupo are `NaN`, all method returns NaN. If there is few NaN and another values non NaN per group, then `interpolate` working perfectly. So only way what is in my mind is replace by some constant - here `mean` should be better like `0`, but also not very nice solution. Best in my opinion is not change `NaN`s after interpolate, only if relly need it.

Comment: @jezrael I didn't notice it earlier but your solution is changing NaN values in the other columns also. But I want to deal with NaN values of Temperature column only.

Comment: @Abhi - Answer was changed - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68403877/revisions)

Comment: @jezrael I think you should check your code once again as it is replacing all the values of 'Temperature' as NaN.

Comment: @Abhi - You are right, added `.to_numpy()`

Comment: @jezrael Yeah now it's working fine. Thank you for your very useful solutions. Your approaches are nice.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to replace the `NaN` in column temperature by an interpolation of the temperature in that specific city.

I would have to think about a more sophisticated solution. But here is a simple hack:

```
df["Rec_times"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Rec_times"]) # .interpolate requires datetime
df["idx"] = df.index # to restore original ordering
df_new = pd.DataFrame() # will hold new data
for (city,group) in df.groupby("City"):
    group = group.set_index("Rec_times", drop=False)
    df_new = pd.concat((df_new, group.interpolate(method='time')))
    
df_new = df_new.set_index("idx").sort_index() # Restore original ordering
df_new
```

Note that interpolation for **Rifle** will yield `NaN` given there is only one data point which is `NaN`.

Comment: If you have any other solution (other than interpolation) which you think can be well suited (for whole df) you can use.